A question on the property of range space of power of a nilpotent operator
Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^5)$ is such that range $T^4 \ne $ range $T^5.$ Prove that $T$ is nilpotent.
My attempt:
Given statement:

If range $T^4 \ne $ range $T^5,$ then $T$ is nilpotent.

Let's consider the contrapositive statement of the given statement.

CONTRAPOSITIVE statement: If $T$ is not nilpotent, then range $T^4 = $ range $T^5.$

If we prove the contrapositive statement, then we, in fact, have proved the given statement and vice versa.
One side inclusion is obvious, i.e., range $T^4 \supset $ range $T^5.$
I am stuck at showing the reverse inclusion.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

If $\operatorname{range}T^4\ne\operatorname{range}T^5$, try to show that $\mathbb C^5\supsetneqq\operatorname{range}T\supsetneqq\operatorname{range}T^2\supsetneqq\operatorname{range}T^3\supsetneqq\operatorname{range}T^4\supsetneqq\operatorname{range}T^5$ and that $\operatorname{range}T^5$ must be zero.

See the answer of lhf here.

I am not able to proceed with this. Can you please elaborate a bit?
